# XSL::Apache FOP java server connection

Tags: apache, perl, apache-fop

Got a project with Apache FOP, have to make a server based application which will use Apache FOP and pick XML+XSLT files, convert it to XSL:FO and then output an PDF file.

Everything works fine until it comes to XSL:FO=>PDF, Im getting a error in my console which tells me:

"could not connect to java server at line 15"

I'm a newbie programmer, and this might be a simple task to complete but I just can't figure it out how to run this bloody java server ... so my code might be working. Any help would be great. (FYI Im working on Windows)

Here is the Perl Code:

```
use XML::LibXSLT;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::ApacheFOP;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xslt   = XML::LibXSLT->new();

my $source    = $parser->parse_file('books.xml');
my $style_doc = $parser->parse_file('books.xsl');

my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($style_doc);

my $results = $stylesheet->transform($source);

my $Fop = XML::ApacheFOP->new();

$Fop->fop( xml => "books.xml", xsl => "books.xsl", outfile => "temp.pdf" )
    or die "cannot create pdf: " . $Fop->errstr;
```

Would be glad to get some help.

Cheers.

Comment: Seriously no one can help me a bit with that task ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run JavaServer by this command

```
/path/to/java -classpath \
/path/to/JavaServer.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/build/fop-0.20.5-RFC3066-patched.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/avalon-framework-cvs-20020806.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/batik.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/xalan-2.4.1.jar\
:/usr/local/xml-fop/lib/xercesImpl-2.2.1.jar \
com.zzo.javaserver.JavaServer
```

This works for me but with fop 0.20 with fop-0.20.5-RFC3066-patched.jar